# group by value in spark python

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I tried for grouping by value from raw key value pairs like

```
[(1, a), (2, a), (3, a), (4, a), (3, b), (1, b), (1, c), (4, c), (4, d)]
```

I'm able to group by key using groupByKey() method but I cant find way to group by value

```
a = [1 , 2 , 3 , 4]
b = [3, 1]
c = [1, 4]
d = [4]
```

I checked in spark API docs but couldnt find any methods

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spark's RDDs have a `groupBy` operator where you can pass a custom groupBy function.

```
data = sc.parallelize([(1, a), (2, a), (3, a), (4, a), (3, b), (1, b), (1, c), (4, c), (4, d)])
data.groupBy(lambda tup: tup[1])
```

That will group the data by the value (second element of tuple). Note that groupBy and groupByKey can cause out of memory exceptions and are expensive operations. See [Avoid GroupByKey](https://databricks.gitbooks.io/databricks-spark-knowledge-base/content/best_practices/prefer_reducebykey_over_groupbykey.html)

Comment: But shuffling is required for aggregating value unlike sum. Sill this is better since you are not interchanging the tuple :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do that by reversing the tuples in RDD,

```
RDD.map(lambda s: reversed(s))

[(1, a), (2, a),....]
```

will became

```
[(a, 1), (a, 2),....]
```

Now groupByKey().

Though I am not sure about efficiency but it will work :)

Answer (score 0):

```
input = sc.parallelize([(1,"a"),(2,"a"),(3,"a"),(4,"a"),(1,"b"),(3,"b"),(1,"c"),(4,"c"),(4,"d")])
input.groupByKey().collect()
output1 = input.map(lambda (x,y):(y,x))
 output2 = output1.groupByKey()
output2.collect()
```

Answer (score -2):

You can Use this script,

It will group by Value.

```
vals = [(1, 'a'), (2, 'a'), (3, 'a'), (4, 'a'), (3, 'b'), (1, 'b'), (1, 'c'), (4, 'c'), (4, 'd')]

lst = {}
for k,v in vals:
    if v in lst.keys():
        lst[v] = lst[v] + [k]
    else:
        lst[v] = [k]
print(lst)
```

Comment: I guess traversing the list and using some aggregating function is not a distributed way, which may end up in wrong result in spark.

Comment: It won't even work since RDDs are not iterable. On a side note you can simply use: `for v, k in vals: lst.setdefault(k, []).append(v)`

Comment: Not a Spark distributed programming idea.